# Word order in an interrogative sentence

Tags: word-order

Please, could you tell me the difference between these sentences:

> Why weren't we informed earlier?
>
> Why were we not informed earlier?

I am not sure about the 2nd sentence actually.

Answer (score 1):

They both sound correct.  The second sentence is the actual, correct ordering, but since there isn't a contraction for "we not", we switch the two words to make the contraction work.  This is very interesting, since

> Why were not we informed earlier?

is wrong, but

> Why weren't we informed earlier?

sounds perfectly natural.

Comment: 'Why (5) (we/not/inform) about this earlier? - this is the task from Advanced Language Practice by Michael Vince. My answer is "Why weren't we informed earlier?" The key says "Why were we not informed earlier?" That's why I am confused a little bit. I asked about the 'not" position after 'we" mostly. Thank you for your reply,